# How can I use Left Ctrl+Alt combination for special characters?

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout

I've been using Ubuntu for few days and I really like it, but I have a problem with my keyboard:
I can't use the <kbd>left Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>left Alt</kbd> combination to type special characters like in Windows.

How can I activate this combination?

Answer (score 3):

Open `Text entry` ,mark input source and press on keyboard icon. You will see all characters available for particular input source.(As you can see not many options for *English (US) layout* but instead you can use *English (US, alternative international) layout*)

[image]
[image]
[image]

If you want to use additional keys open *keyboard>shortcuts>typing* and set a **Compose key** and **Alternative characters key**. The latter is used to write additional keys of present keyboard layout (My guess is that's what you've been looking for).

[image]

In this case I have set <kbd>RCtrl</kbd> as Alternative characters key. Note that you can set only one key for this and not a combo like <kbd>LCtrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>, which is by all means simpler. You can change the layout however suites you to gain missing keys, but I don't think you can rebind the way you want and not create further mess with your system.

---

The [Compose key](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ComposeKey#Compose%20key%20sequences) is used to write special characters(lets say it is AltGr):

<kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> then release followed by <kbd>a</kbd>+<kbd>e</kbd> will produce <kbd>æ</kbd>.

To write [Unicode Characters](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/GtkComposeTable) press:
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>u</kbd>, you will get underline <kbd>u</kbd> then release and type the Unicode without the leading zeros, e. g.:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>u</kbd> followed by <kbd>a</kbd><kbd>e</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd> will produce <kbd>®</kbd>, or

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>u</kbd> followed by<kbd>1</kbd><kbd>f</kbd><kbd>4</kbd><kbd>4</kbd><kbd>f</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd> will produce

You can use *Character map* to drag and drop any of the symbols you need.

Useful, but little old [link](http://fsymbols.com/keyboard/linux/).

Comment: Is CTRL+SHIFT = "Alternative characters key" or something else? Note that these two settings under *typing* are set to "Disabled" by default.

Comment: Only one can be assign. I guess they are disabled because otherwise they will loose their functions. What's your point actually?

Comment: "Only one" in what regard? Mine are disabled in the meaning that I cannot change them (as I can do with the other ones; to switch keyboard layout). My point: What you have written above is not entirely clear, to me at least. The 'Compose' key as shown above, and by `Text entry` (on my screen) is not available on my keyboard.

Comment: I hope the edit will clarify everything misunderstood.

Comment: It does: Now I found MY problem, and this is a detail still missing above: You have to click on the RIGHT HAND SIDE COLUMN to get anywhere with `Compose key` and `Alternative Characters key`. The `... source` items gets "change mode" activated also by clicks on the LEFT COLUMN - which does NOT happen for those mentioned earlier.

Answer (score -1):

On Ubuntu, you have to use <kbd>AltGr</kbd>.

This key is also the one you can/should use in Windows, but as Windows predates the <kbd>AltGr</kbd> key, they (still) treat <kbd>AltGr</kbd> and the combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd> the same way (most of the time) whereas <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd> is used for navigation under Ubuntu.

Comment: Also look at http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/84707, but there seems to be no real solution...